# Predicate and Propositional function?

Tags: functions, logic

What's the difference between a predicate and a propositional function, both in mathematical aspect and logical aspect?

I also see some texts in wikipedia, which made me confused.
*"Later Russell examined the problem of whether propositional functions were predicative or not, and he proposed two theories to try to get at this question: the zig-zag theory and the ramified theory of types."*

Answer (score 1):

In modern terms, i.e. using in first order logic, we can say that a *predicate* is symbolized with a *predicate letter* $P(x)$ while a *propositional function* is expressed by an *open formula* $\varphi(x)$.

For a brief overview, see [Classical Logic: Language](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#2).

---

Regarding the evolution of Russell's theories, from [paradoxes](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/) to [type theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/), you can see: Nicholas Griffin (editor), [The Cambridge Companion to Bertrand Russell](https://books.google.it/books?id=obY48lTt-2AC&pg=PR5) (2003) :

- **Ch.5 Bertrand Russell’s Logicism** by Martin Godwyn and Andrew Irvine,
- **Ch.6 The Theory of Descriptions** by Peter Hylton,
- **Ch.7 Russell’s Substitutional Theory** by Gregory Landini,
- **Ch.8 The Theory of Types** by Alasdair Urquhart;

as well as :

- Alasdair Urquhart, "Russell's zig-zag path to the ramified theory of types" (1988), Russell,8: 82–91.

Comment: Thanks for answering! It's my first time to hear the noun "open formula". I searched wikipeida just now, seeing that _"In mathematical logic, a non-closed formula is a formula which contains free variables. (Note that in logic, a "sentence" is a formula without free variables, and a formula is "open" if it contains no quantifiers, which disagrees with the terminology of this article.) Unlike closed formulas, which contain constants, non-closed formulas do not express propositions; they are neither true nor false. "_

Comment: It makes me confused again. What is the critical difference between a _propositional function P(x)_  and a _open formula phi(x)_ ? wikipedia's description is a little bit messing.

Comment: @Eric - in [First order arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) with $<$ as a binary predicate (i.e. $<(x,y)$) the following is an open formula : $\exists z (x < z)$; as you can see, the variable $x$ is not quantified in the formula, i.e. it is *free*.