# What is Propositional function in propositional calculus?

Tags: logic

I am studying propositional logic and little bit confused with [Propositional function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_function). It is part of propositional calculus and it is similar to predicate. But predicates are part of [First-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) - also known as predicate logic.

Do I understand correctly that we can look at propositional function in two different ways: as proposition (Propositional logic) and as function (FOL)?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1740835/is-there-a-difference-between-a-propositional-function-and-a-wff) as well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631812/predicate-and-propositional-function)

Comment: Presumably, there is an error in Wiki's article; the definition of *propositional function* (or [open formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_formula)) applies to predicate logic.

Comment: Squaring propositional functions and propositions maybe involves thinking of the latter as constant-valued propositional functions? (Not saying that I agree with this usage.)